# How do I create a Wireshark DissectorTable suitable for chaining in Lua?

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm trying to dissect a proprietary protocol encapsulated in UDP packets.  The protocol is multi-layer with a very simple header in the lowest layer.  That header has a type field to indicate the format of the higher layer protocol.

Chaining my lowest protocol to a UDP port number is easy with plenty of examples to follow.  What I don't understand is how to create a DissectorTable based on the type field so I can chain the higher level protocols.

I have ProtoField objects for each of the fields of the low level protocol that are used to display it in the tree.  How do I associate a DissectorTable and its Dissectors with the values in the type field?  Do I even need to populate the DissectorTable before the higher level protocols add themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a new DissectorTable for your protocol using the `DissectorTable.new()` function with the appropriate arguments, which you would do outside of your `proto.dissector()` definition, and then invoke the created table inside your `proto.dissector()` function by calling `mydissectortable:try()` with the appropriate arguments.  Other Lua dissectors (i.e., your higher-level ones) would register into this table like they do normal C-code based dissector tables, using `DissectorTable.get()` and `dissectortable:add()`.